# System.NullReferenceException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #DF5EC476

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Hi I'm getting this error in CRM, Can anyone help me how to resolve this error.

System.NullReferenceException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #DF5EC476

Comment: where are you getting this error? can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it means that a code refers to a property of a not initialized variable.
You can see more details of the error in MSCRM trace by using the reference number DF5EC476.
I cannot help you with online deployment, but if your system is on-premise deployment, you can do the following (in a server where MSCRM is installed):

1. Go to the registry by typing regedit in Windows Run or in Windows Search.
2. Locate the following HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSCRM registry subkey.
3. Look into TraceDirectory entry value - this is the directory where trace files are created.
4. Open it and search for the number. You may need to see what happened before and after to locate the actual cause.

Pay attention if the trace is enabled. It is controlled by TraceEnabled entry. Value 1 means it is enabled and value 0 means it is not. So, if it is disabled you can enable it by changing the value to 1 and by changing a value of the TraceRefresh entry (just change the number to what number you want between 0 and 99 or create the entry with a value if it does not exist). Using by TraceRefresh allows applying changes in other entries without restarting MSCRM website or performing IIS reset. Sure, if you've just enabled the trace you have to reproduce the situation that fails with the error. The reference number will change, so use it instead of the previous one.

More information about MSCRM trace can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/dynamics/crm/how-to-enable-tracing-in-dynamics-crm